# Creating array with spread syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

Here is a JavaScript arrow function I found in a React book:

```
const createArray = (length) => [...Array(length)];
```

Why not simply return a new array?

```
const createArray = (length) => Array(length);
```

If I log the result of `createArray(7)` with either of the definitions, I get the same result:

```
(7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

What does the first definition achieve as compared to the second one?

Comment: `Array(5)` => `[empty x 5]` vs. `[...Array(5)]` => `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`. The difference is initialisation.

Comment: In which environment you're getting the same result?

Comment: Using code sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways of creating an array are *different*. They do not produce the same result.

Second way of creating an array will create a sparse array with only `length` own property and no index properties. You can see this using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`

```js
const arr = new Array(5);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr));
```

Using the spread syntax will create an array will index properties as shown in the following code example:

```js
const arr = [...new Array(5)];
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I could quickly change the log statement to dump getOwnPropertyNames() and it showed the first method giving all the index properties along with length property whereas the second one only dumped the length property

Answer (score 3):

`Array(length);` will create a *sparse array* - one with no own-properties (except `length`), which cannot be iterated over with the array iteration methods:

```js
const arr = new Array(7);

console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty('4'));
arr.forEach(() => {
  console.log('iteration');
});
```

In contrast, utilizing spread syntax will populate the new array properly:

```js
const arr = [...new Array(7)];

console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty('4'));
arr.forEach(() => {
  console.log('iteration');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

i hope if you want its example here.

More Information = > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```
const testArr = [
        { name: false, expected: false },
        { name: null, expected: false },
        { name: undefined, expected: false },
        { name: "", expected: false },
        { name: "  \t\n", expected: false },
    ];
    
    const createArray = (arr) => { return [...arr]}
    
    console.log(createArray(testArr))
```